# 'Learning' Animal Guesser Program

Tags: rust, binary-tree

I've written a program that uses a binary tree to essentially 'learn' about animals given the name and questions about them. Learn is probably a little strong of a word, all it does is store the questions using bincode (pre-release `2.0.0-rc.2`) and ask them later to figure out what the user is talking about.

```
#![warn(clippy::pedantic, clippy::nursery, rust_2018_idioms)]

use std::{fs::File, io::Seek, path::PathBuf};

use bincode::{Decode, Encode};

#[derive(Encode, Decode, Debug)]
enum Btree {
    Branch {
        question: String,
        // No
        left: Box<Btree>,
        // Yes
        right: Box<Btree>,
    },
    Leaf {
        animal: String,
    },
}

impl Btree {
    fn get_current(&self, current: &[bool]) -> &Self {
        let mut tree = self;
        for &i in current {
            // Should always be a branch
            if let Self::Branch {
                question: _,
                left,
                right,
            } = tree
            {
                if i {
                    tree = right;
                } else {
                    tree = left;
                }
            } else {
                unreachable!()
            }
        }
        tree
    }

    fn get_current_mut(&mut self, current: &[bool]) -> &mut Self {
        let mut tree = self;
        for &i in current {
            // Should always be a branch
            if let Self::Branch {
                question: _,
                left,
                right,
            } = tree
            {
                if i {
                    tree = right;
                } else {
                    tree = left;
                }
            } else {
                unreachable!()
            }
        }
        tree
    }
}

fn create_db(db_path: PathBuf) {
    println!("Database not found, creating now");
    let mut db_file = std::fs::File::create(db_path).expect("Couldn't create database file");
    let animal1: String =
        promptly::prompt("Please enter the name of an animal").expect("Couldn't read answer");
    let animal2: String =
        promptly::prompt("Please enter the name of another animal").expect("Couldn't read answer");
    let question: String = promptly::prompt(format!(
        "Please write a yes/no question to differentiate between a(n) {animal1} and a(n) {animal2}"
    ))
    .expect("Couldn't read question");
    let animal_yesno: bool = promptly::prompt(format!(
        "Does 'yes' in your question correspond to a {animal1}?"
    ))
    .expect("Couldn't read answer");
    let btree = if animal_yesno {
        Btree::Branch {
            question,
            left: Box::new(Btree::Leaf { animal: animal2 }),
            right: Box::new(Btree::Leaf { animal: animal1 }),
        }
    } else {
        Btree::Branch {
            question,
            left: Box::new(Btree::Leaf { animal: animal1 }),
            right: Box::new(Btree::Leaf { animal: animal2 }),
        }
    };
    bincode::encode_into_std_write(btree, &mut db_file, bincode::config::standard())
        .expect("Couldn't save database");
}

fn read_db() -> Option<(Btree, File)> {
    let db_path: PathBuf =
        promptly::prompt("Enter the database path").expect("Couldn't read database path");
    let mut db_file = if let Ok(db_file) = std::fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .read(true)
        .write(true)
        .open(&db_path)
    {
        db_file
    } else {
        create_db(db_path);
        return None;
    };
    Some((
        bincode::decode_from_std_read(&mut db_file, bincode::config::standard())
            .expect("Couldn't parse database"),
        db_file,
    ))
}

fn main() {
    let (mut db, mut db_file) = match read_db() {
        Some(dbs) => dbs,
        None => return,
    };
    let mut current_db = Vec::new();
    loop {
        match db.get_current(&current_db) {
            Btree::Branch {
                question,
                left: _,
                right: _,
            } => {
                let ans: bool = promptly::prompt(question).expect("Couldn't read answer");
                if ans {
                    current_db.push(true);
                } else {
                    current_db.push(false);
                }
            }
            Btree::Leaf { animal } => {
                let ans: bool = promptly::prompt(format!("Is your animal a(n) {animal}?"))
                    .expect("Couldn't read answer");
                if ans {
                    println!("Yay!");
                    break;
                }
                let new_animal: String = promptly::prompt("Please enter the name of your animal")
                    .expect("Couldn't read answer");
                let new_question: String = promptly::prompt(format!("Please write a yes/no question to differentiate between a(n) {new_animal} and a(n) {animal}")).expect("Couldn't read question");
                let new_animal_yesno: bool = promptly::prompt(format!(
                    "Does 'yes' in your question correspond to a(n) {new_animal}?"
                ))
                .expect("Couldn't read answer");
                let animal = animal.clone();
                let parent = db.get_current_mut(&current_db[0..current_db.len() - 1]);
                let parent = if let Btree::Branch {
                    question: _,
                    left,
                    right,
                } = parent
                {
                    if *current_db.last().unwrap() {
                        right
                    } else {
                        left
                    }
                } else {
                    unreachable!();
                };
                *parent = if new_animal_yesno {
                    Box::new(Btree::Branch {
                        question: new_question,
                        left: Box::new(Btree::Leaf { animal }),
                        right: Box::new(Btree::Leaf { animal: new_animal }),
                    })
                } else {
                    Box::new(Btree::Branch {
                        question: new_question,
                        left: Box::new(Btree::Leaf { animal: new_animal }),
                        right: Box::new(Btree::Leaf { animal }),
                    })
                };
                db_file.rewind().expect("Couldn't truncate database");
                bincode::encode_into_std_write(db, &mut db_file, bincode::config::standard())
                    .expect("Couldn't save database");
                println!("Database changes saved");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm hoping to be able to find a better way to navigate down the tree instead of using a `Vec<bool>`. If possible, I'm also hoping for a better way to get around the `can't have an immutable and mutable reference at the same time` error that I tried to fix with `let animal = animal.clone()`. Of course, any other improvements are also welcome.

Comment: If I remove the `let animal = animal.clone()` I get an error about mismatching types, not a borrowing error.

Comment: Yes, sorry. The way I originally had it was having `animal` cloned in the if statement where it modifies `parent`. Having that without the `let animal = animal.clone()` line causes the borrowing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to tree data structures in Rust, you have three options:

Firstly, you can write your algorithm recursively. So you could write a function something like:

```
  fn play_game(node: &mut Btree) {
         // either:
         play_game(node.left);
         // or:
         play_game(node.right);
         // or:
         *node = Btree {
            // replace the node
          }
     }
```

Secondly, you can use indexes to keep track your location in the tree. This is essentially what you've done with `current_db` which keep track of the location of the current node. You can go a little further and always use indexes, even with the data structure itself.

```
enum Node {
    Branch {
        question: String,
        left: usize,
        right: usize,
    },
    Leaf {
        animal: String,
    },
}
```

In this case `left` and `right` would be indexes into a `Vec<Node>` on a basic tree object. Then just keep track of simpler `usize` indexes to know which node you are working with.

Thirdly, you can use `RefCell`. Instead of `Box<Btree>` use `Box<RefCell<Btree>>`. RefCell has interior mutability, you can modify the interior of the `RefCell` even if you don't have a mutable reference to the `RefCell` itself. This means that you can navigate and manipulate the parts of the tree more easily at the cost of extra runtime checking.

Personally, I favor the first option when my algorithm is naturally suited to running recursively on trees. I favor the second option when I need to freely manipulate a tree. I pretty much never take the third option.

As for the `animal.clone()` issue:

If you rewrite your game playing algorithm in a recursive fashion, it should be possible to avoid it. Basically, you need to write the algorithm in such a way that Rust realize that you are replacing the same `Btree` that you taking the `animal` `String` from, so its okay to move it.

But in the event that proves tricky, there is an alternative:

```
let animal = std::mem::replace(animal, String::new());
```

This will replace the original animal name with a temporary empty string (which will not allocate and thus be cheaper than cloning the string) and gives you the original animal `String` for whatever use you might put it to.

Comment: Thanks! Would `mem::take` work instead of `mem::replace` to swap the animal string?

Comment: @ravenclaw900, yes, I forgot about `mem::take`